# Browserstack locale error while running e2e test using protractor in jenkins :Locale error:Couldn't connect to files

Tags: jenkins, browserstack

I am using  browser stack plugin in Jenkins for e2e testing using protractor.
E2e is working fine locally but when deployed in Jenkins run e2e test getting the following error.

```
Connecting local error { LocalError: Could not connect to Files!
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Angular UI Toolkit\node_modules     \browserstack-local\lib\Local.js:57:20
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
name: 'LocalError',
message: 'Could not connect to Files!',
extra: undefined }
```

This is my browser stack.config file.

```
    var browserstack = require('browserstack-local');

    exports.config = {
    'seleniumAddress': 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',

    ignoreSynchronization: false,
    framework: 'jasmine',

    allScriptsTimeout: 110000,
    getPageTimeout: 50000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
    // showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000000
     },
      specs: [
       './dist/demo-app/**/*.e2e-spec.js'
       ],

       exclude: [],

       'capabilities': {
       'browserstack.user': 'username',
       'browserstack.key': 'key',
       'browserstack.local': true,
       'browserstack.localIdentifier':'test123',
       'os': 'Windows',
       'os_version': '8.1',
      'browserName': 'IE',
      'browser_version': '11.0'
      },

      // Code to start browserstack local before start of test
      beforeLaunch: function(){
       console.log("Connecting local");
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        exports.bs_local_args = {
          key: exports.config.capabilities['browserstack.key'],
          localIdentifier:exports.config.capabilities['browserstack.localIdentifier'],
          force: true
        };
      exports.bs_local = new browserstack.Local();
       console.log('exports.bs_local BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME...',process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME);
       console.log('exports.bs_local...',exports.bs_local);
      exports.bs_local.start(exports.bs_local_args, function(error) {

        if (error){
          console.log("Connecting local error",error);
          return reject(error);
        } 

        console.log('Connected. Now testing...');

        resolve();
      });
    });
  },

      // Code to stop browserstack local after end of test
      afterLaunch: function(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          exports.bs_local.stop(resolve);
        });
       },
         useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding 'logFile' to my configuration

```
 exports.bs_local_args = {
          key: exports.config.capabilities['browserstack.key'],
          localIdentifier:exports.config.capabilities['browserstack.localIdentifier'],
          force: true
          logFile: '<path-to-log>'
        };
```